# Regular expression to get data between semicolon

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
lemap;Brsjmnb008528;Ask Toolbar;APNLLC;09/04/2014
```

I would like build a regular expression to get complete words before first semicolon, another one to get only all the words between first and second semicolon, etc.

Like this for the first use case:

```
[^;]*
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any comma's in your string...

Comment: You mean.. semicolon?

Comment: If you're using a programming language like PHP, then use the `split` function to break apart the string into an array.

Comment: Split on semicolons, what's the point of a regex here?

Comment: @Dukeling, if I did it was an honest mistake, I'll check the history and see where I went wrong. PS: Did you see the phrasing before though?

Comment: @bitoiu Fair enough, I thought I'd just point it out. The difference between "etc" and not might seem minor (the "etc" might even seem like an error), but it is the difference between "I want the first two parts" and "I want all the parts". But if the question is indeed "I want all the parts" (as it appears to be based on OP's actions), we're left guessing the answer, as that regex is correct to get the required information - the problem likely relates to the usage, or limitations / differences of the regex engine (which is confirmed by the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex:

```
[^;]*
```

should work, but maybe you just need to capture what you match:

```
([^;]*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is also matching null, ex: lemap;Brsjmnb008528; is matched as  (lemap   null   Brsjmnb008528  null)

Answer (score 1):

With this one:

```
^([^;]+);([^;]+);
```

you'll have the first word in group 1 and the second in group 2.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 
`[^;]+`
Using  `[^;]*` will match the nulls also

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[^;]*
```

to get first word. `^` at the beginning matches the beginning of a string.